# FindShortestPath in Markov Transition Matrix

Tags: graphs-and-networks, markov-chains

So I have a part of transition matrix like this.

```
 tmat={{0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
       0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0,
       0.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
      0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
      0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
      0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
```

And I converted this to DiscreteMarkovProcess

```
mark = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, tmat];
graph = Graph[mark,EdgeLabels -> {DirectedEdge[i_, j_] :> 
MarkovProcessProperties[mark, "TransitionMatrix"][[i, j]]}];
sp = FindShortestPath[graph, 1, 10]
HighlightGraph[graph, sp]
```

[image]

So is there a simple way to find the shortest path by edge weight, like the path is selected by highest transition probability? For example for 1-> 3, it will go via 14 instead the 2.

Also can we hide or remove the disjointed states like 13, 15 ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start from base graph:

```
g = Graph[DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, tmat]];
```

Remove isolated vertices:

```
graph = Subgraph[g, Flatten[Select[WeaklyConnectedComponents[g], Length[#] > 1 &]], Options[g]];
```

Set weights, coords, and label edges (reverse weight value to find highest path):

```
vcoords = 
 GraphEmbedding[g][[VertexIndex[g, #] & /@ VertexList[graph]]];
weight = MarkovProcessProperties[mark, "TransitionMatrix"][[##]] & @@@
    EdgeList[graph];
wgraph = Graph[graph, EdgeWeight -> 1/weight, 
  EdgeLabels -> Thread[EdgeList[graph] -> weight], VertexCoordinates -> vcoords]; 

sp = FindShortestPath[wgraph, 1, 10]
```

> {1, 14, 3, 4, 5, 18, 7, 8, 9, 10}

```
HighlightGraph[wgraph, PathGraph[sp, DirectedEdges -> True], 
 GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"]
```

Comment: @ halmir  this works. Thanks. The plot flipped into mirror image when using `Graph[WeaklyConnectedGraphComponents[g][[1]], Options[g]]`; Is there way to plot as original?

Comment: I updated answer.